# Need help iterating through smaller 2D "subarrays" found in larger 2D array

Tags: java, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am working on a project that requires finding some smaller 2d int arrays contained within a larger 2d int array.

To be more specific, I will be provided with a text file for input. The text file will contain an N, M, and K value, as well as integers to populate a "large" MxN grid. I will then need to find all "small" KxK grids within that larger MxN grid, and return the largest int within each KxK grid.

So, for example:
m = 3; n = 4; k = 2

MxN:
3 4 2
2 3 1
8 3 2
7 8 1

The 1st KxK grid to analyze would be:
3 4
2 3
return 4;

The 2nd:
4 2
3 1
return 4;

The 3rd:
2 3
8 3
return 8;

etc, etc.

Is there a slick way of iterating through these KxK grids with the mod operator or something? I feel like there is a simple solution for this, but it's not obvious to me.

I know this is more of a math problem than a programming one, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to write little code here:

```
private int[] getMaxFromGrids(int k, int[][] yourArray){

    int m = yourArray.length;    //height of grid
    int n = yourArray[0].length; //width of grid, assuming that all inner array have same length!
                                 //argument k is size of smaller grid

    //computing max possibilities to fit smaller grid to larger one
    int maxPossibilities = (m - k + 1) * (n - k + 1);

    if(maxPossibilities < 1 || k < 1) return null;

    int[] maxValuesSmallGrid = new int[maxPossibilities];
    for (int i = 0; i < (maxPossibilities); i++) {

        //computing actual start element for small grid
        int colStartElement = i % (n - (k - 1));
        int rowStartElement = i / (n - (k - 1));

        //creating smaller grid
        int[] smallGrid = new int[k * k];
        int o = 0; //index of smaller grid
        for (int j = colStartElement; j < colStartElement + k; j++) {
            for (int l = rowStartElement; l < rowStartElement + k; l++) {
                smallGrid[o++] = yourArray[j][l];
            }
        }

        maxValuesSmallGrid[i] = getMax(smallGrid);
    }

    return maxValuesSmallGrid;
}

//method for getting max number from given array
private int getMax(int[] numbers) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int num : numbers) {
        if(num > max) max = num;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that K<=N && K<=M, you can easily find all subarray2d by moving their top left corner from 0,0 to N-K,M-K (use 2 for loops)

Then make a function taking the coordinates of the top left corner of a K*K subarray2d and returning its higher value :)